# Is it natural to answer a yes-no question with just yes/no?

Tags: questions

Given a yes-no question such as:

> Did you call him?

Is it idiomatic to simply answer:

> Yes. / No.

As opposed to:

> Yes, I did. / No, I didn't.

or just:

> I did. / I didn't.

I've noticed that in some languages simply answering *yes* or *no* seems to be the common unmarked way of answering (e.g. Spanish), but not in others (e.g. Portuguese).

Comment: It depends entirely on the situation and the person answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Yes.` just on its own can sound very abrupt. I would not use it like that with a superior or client. To answer with one word and not continue the conversation is awkward. It's not really the yes on its own, but rather the silence afterwards. `Yes, blah blah details blah` would be more normal.

To a client or superior, I would say `Yes, I did.` if I had no more detail to give.

To a peer, or in an informal context, I would say `yup` or `ja`, both accepted variations on yes for my area.

Answer (score 1):

All three variations are natural and grammatical. By itself, though, "yes" can seem too brusque to a listener or reader.